# Python Logistic Regression Perfect Separation Error

Tags: python, logistic-regression

My issue is perfect separation with a logistic model testing two binary factors and their interaction on the dependent variable. When I do not include the interaction term, the model works, when I include the interaction term I get

> "PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not
>   available"

There is already a question answered on perfect separation for logistic regression, but this question specifically pertains to perfect separation error with an interaction term in the model.

Here is my data
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcb2q.png)

My code:

```
endog_cols = df.columns[1:3]

exog_cols = df.columns[4:8]

logit2 = sm.GLM(df[endog_cols], df[exog_cols], family = sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run logistic regression due to "perfect separation error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668868/unable-to-run-logistic-regression-due-to-perfect-separation-error)

Comment: Your intercept term is constant and can't be be fit as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668868/unable-to-run-logistic-regression-due-to-perfect-separation-error)

Comment: I understand that. However, I have a constant intercept in the same model without interaction and I get no error. Could I ask your advice on how I would revise the intercept so it doesn't cause the error?

Comment: I can't speak for the specific implementation of GLM you are using, but most methods include the intercept as part of the model and therefore don't need you to specify it as a column.

Comment: statsmodels GLM method, the one I used, requires an intercept to be included manually in the exogenous vectors.

Comment: For stats models that is only true when you aren't specifying the model using a formula: ["An intercept is not included by default and should be added by the user (models specified using a formula include an intercept by default)"](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html).  This would also explain why it works when you don't include the interaction but breaks when you do.